# Vegetation Change Tracker and GEE: What bands are required?

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat

I'm hoping to use the GEE implementation of the Vegetation Change Tracker (VCT) algorithm here: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-algorithms-temporalsegmentation-vct#javascript

I'm struggling to identify the band requirements for the `timeSeries` argument. The docs indicate the following:

1. B3
2. B4
3. B5
4. B7
5. thermal
6. NDVI
7. DNBR
8. COMP

Bands 1-6 are straight forward enough but 7 and 8 are confusing. DNBR (7) is differenced Normalized Burn Ratio I think, but I would expect to pass NBR for a time series... What is COMP (8)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the COMP is the composite z-score AKA Integrated Forest Z-Score (IFZ). Computed as follows (from Huang et al, 2010, RSE):

[image]
Where bi is any pixel from a band (b) and bi-hat is

[image]
Where NB is number of bands used.

https://groups.google.com/g/google-earth-engine-developers/c/g0mM92B4Y14/m/JVF5ve9_GQAJ

There are still lots of unclear bits in the documentation...The landcover map for example gives no indication of what landcover classes are required.